# Multi Schema Databases

Tags: schema, multi-tenant

We have an SAAS type of environment. Using SQL Sever 2008.
Having hundreds of clients the approach was taking into creating separate databases per client, obviously with 100's of them its unmanageble.
Does anybody have experience with separating tables into different schemas? if so has anybody done 50+ schemas per database?

Thanks

Comment: We used MySQL with ~4000 schemas/databases. Btw, in MySQL schema and database are synonymous. I think MSSQL should be able to handle similar number of schemas with ease.

Answer (score 0):

That's really bad practise in my opinion. Using a single schema with one to many relationships to connect tables is a much better approach. SQL Server can handle hundreds of thousands of records without breaking a sweat.